# 60 секунд - всегда 60

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

[image: Скриншот]

Насколько я понимаю, это сообщение означает, что ответы можно отправлять ответы раз в минуту. Но в текущей формулировке оно воспринимается как "до возможности отправки следующего ответа осталось 60 секунд". Это бы тоже было неплохо (пожалуй, даже лучше), если бы в таком случае таймер изменялся при повторном нажатии. Т. е. сейчас 60 секунд, если я нажму через 5 секунд, то должно оказаться 55. Но сейчас остаётся 60. Поэтому делаю вывод, что сообщение надо заменить.

Comment: <этоНеБагЭтоФича> через 60 секунд **гарантированно** станет можно :)</этоНеБагЭтоФича>

Comment: Использовал выбранную сообществом строку. Но! На мой взгляд фраза стала более непонятной, чем была. На сколько я помню, если публиковать серию вопросов, интервал может увеличиваться. То есть «это действие» зависит от предыдущих.

Comment: Но ведь "это действие" есть и в оригинальной фразе.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky кстати, в мобильном приложении выводится именно актуальное (оставшееся) кол-во секунд до следующей попытки. Поэтому странно, что в web-версии этого нет.

Comment: @alexolut, кстати, а мобильное приложение использует ту же локализацию?

Comment: @Qwertiy какие-то строки точно общие. Но видимо не все.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если время захардкожено во фразе, то

> Вы можете выполнять это действие не чаще раза в минуту

Если важно сохранить секунды, то

> Вы можете выполнять это действие раз в 60 секунд

Answer (score 2):

Оставить текущее сообщение

> Вы можете повторить это действие через 60 секунд

Answer (score 0):

> Интервал между такими действиями должен быть не менее 60 секунд

Слово "такими" хочется на что-нибудь заменить. Но "однотипными" не подходит, потому что не любые однотипные действия требуют 60 секунд - вроде где-то было 5.